# copy data from one table to another aftersave using yii framework

Tags: yii

i have this code snippet. i want to copy data from one table to another..plz see my code this is not working.

thanks

```
protected function afterSave()
 //Copy data from Client to packageassignment ***
  // assuming     your you're in the Client model 
    //and Client has id,package_id,p_start_date
 {
    $packageassignment= new Packageassignment();
    $packageassignment->user_id=$this->id;
    $packageassignment->package_id=$this->package_id;
    $packageassignment->package_start_date=$this->p_start_date;
    $packageassignment->save();
    return parent::afterSave();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Likely the problem is in the line

```
$packageassignment->save();
```

Change that to

```
if(!$packageassignment->save()){
  echo 'packageassignment save failed!';
  //other debugging code
}
```

and then see if it gives an error. Or replace with your preferred error logging techniques.

Comment: Renzem,i changed the code as you described but no data is saving nor echo message for failed.

plz advise..only data save in first table not in second.thanks

Comment: @MuhammadHamdani At this point you just need to do standard debugging techniques to narrow down the problem. Add an echo statement for success too. Make sure you aren't redirecting after save, else the output from the `echo` statements will be lost. You can also try to simply save the `Packageassignment` model by itself, inputting some arbitrary values, just to see if it works. That's all you're looking for, make sure that save works on its own. Check the rules() method of that model and make sure that they are correct. Try with `$packageassignment->save(false);` to ignore any validation.